# Computer Trying to Load Roaming Profile from Wrong Location

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, roaming-profile

I'm working with a Windows Server 2008 R2 AD DC ("SERVER1") and a Windows 7 Professional desktop ("DESKTOPELIA") that has been added to my domain.

I've set the profile path for my test account to

> "\server1\UserProfiles\%USERNAME%"

but when I login to the account from the DESKTOPELIA it loads a temporary profile and displays an error:

> "\DESKTOPELIA\UserProfiles can not be found."

Previously, Roaming Profile was working for this account after I'd "Set Roaming Profile Path for all users logging into this computer" policy "Computer Configuration->Policies->System->User Profiles" for the default group policy.

I subsequently tried to setup Folder Redirection, at which point DESKTOPELIA ceased to access the romaing profile correctly. I tried various redirection configs to no avail, and ultimately reverted all folders back to their default state. I've also restarted both computer and server and run Gpupdate.exe to no avail.

My questions are:

1. Why is DESKTOPELIA substituting it's self for SERVER1 in the User Profile path?
2. How do I fix that, such that it loads and saves the User Profile from SERVER1?